# Placeholder in inner functions in scala

Tags: scala

Here is the simple code:

```
(0 to 20).foreach(print(math.pow(2, _)))
```

I was wondering, why it doesn't work, but this similar code

```
(0 to 20).foreach(x => print(math.pow(2, x)))
```

do work. What's the problem with using the placeholder inside the inner function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala uses underscores to create an anonymous function with the smallest expression that isn't the identity function.

So the compiler first tries:

```
(0 to 20).foreach(print(x => math.pow(2, x => x)))
```

Nope, that's the identity function, so it goes out one set of parentheses and tries:

```
(0 to 20).foreach(print(x => math.pow(2, x)))
```

That is a nontrivial anonymous function, so it stops there.